# Maven Issue: strings in switch are not supported in -source 1.5 [ERROR] (use -source 7 or higher to enable strings in switch)

Tags: java, maven

When I try to compile my maven i get this errors:

```
strings in switch are not supported in -source 1.5 [ERROR] (use -source 7 or higher to enable strings in switch)
```

It complains about the switch. see in the pic.
I've also attached my POM.XML.

[image]

Comment: Unable to add the pom. if needed I will print screen it.

Comment: Don't post screenshots of things that can be posted as text (code formatted).

Answer (score 2):

`Switch` with `string` as argument is only supported by java  1.7 or higher. You compile with target version 1.5 which is the default for maven.

Add the following lines to your pom:

```
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source><Java_version></maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target><Java_version></maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
```

where `<Java_version>` is 1.7 or higher for example

```
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
```

For more informations see https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html

Comment: After adding this and running the "clean+install" which worked fine --> maven compilation passed. But still, the class Utils I sent here present the failure on the switch case:

Comment: @Ofer you mean in intellj it does not compile?

Comment: @Ofer Recreate the Project after the pom changes